# Creating an HTTP connection via Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am creating an [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) client to execute a PHP file in my server and this is the code:

```
try
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://yasinahmed.cpa10.com/sendnoti.php");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    Toast.makeText(GCMMainActivity.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Toast.makeText(GCMMainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Many times I used this code and it's working without a problem, but this time when I execute the code it always go to the exception and prints the error. This time, I used AVD with Google API level 17, so is this the problem or is there another problem in the code?

Comment: What exception/error you are getting? Can you post your Logcat output?

Comment: the exception is 
Android.os.NetworkInMainThreadException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. Run your code in AsyncTask:

```
class Preprocessing extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try
        {
           HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://yasinahmed.cpa10.com/sendnoti.php");
           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);  
           return true;      
       }
       catch(Exception e)
      {        
           return false;
      }
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result)
            Toast.makeText(GCMMainActivity.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(GCMMainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Call this class in your Activity:

```
new Preprocessing ().execute();
```

Don't forget to add this to AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Jaguar : Big thanks it works now fine , but why in my code doesn't work since its work probably in other projects ?! does the version of android make different ? and do you have any article about async to read ?

Comment: @user2597622 It was working since you was using older Android version which supports network operations on main thread

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know the error. But since I have to guess, my bet is that you are trying to execute this code on the main event thread (a.k.a. the UI thread). That was always wrong and as of API level 11, it will cause a [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) to be thrown. See the document [Designing for Responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html) for the proper way to handle networking in Android.

Comment: i try to execute it in button clicklistner function

Comment: @user2597622 - That's at least part of the problem, then. The listener is called on the event thread. You need to start a worker thread (for example, an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)) to initiate network connections.